# Redirection using htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a website and I need the following redirections :

- www.example.com > example.com
- http requests redirected to https

I wrote the following rules :

```
#Redirect http://example.com to https://example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]

#Redirect www to non-www
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

The rules are not working and I'm getting the error : domain.com redirected you too many times.

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first rule seems to be the culprit which is not checking for `http / https` and redirecting to `https`.

You may use:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Redirect www to non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that but it's not working unfortunately. Still getting the same error : redirected you too many times.

Comment: I put only this rule in my .htaccess file and I'm in incognito mode. I checked, when putting some random strings, there is an error on the page, which means htaccess file is taken into account. Do you know where this can come from please ? Thanks

Comment: Here is a screenshot : https://ibb.co/qD4GN98 basically I'm getting a loop of 19 requests with status 301 and the twenthied fails. Yes I'm behind a reverse proxy configured as follows : https://ibb.co/HCFNdqX

Comment: It's Apache 2.4.41

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208661/discussion-between-anubhava-and-thomas-carlton).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of Anubhava, I could get a working solution :

```
#Redirect http://example.com to https://example.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} =off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]

#Redirect www to non www
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```